# How can I customise ORM query's retrieved data in cakephp3?

Tags: php, orm, cakephp-3.0

I'm pulling out data from our DB and I need to customise the returned string as still part of the query object.

I tried manipulating the data directly from the "fields" param but doesn't seem to work.

```
$query = $this->controller->Orders->find('all', [
            'fields' => [
                'Feedback.record_num', order_id', 'feedback_date', 'one_year_submitted', 
                 'full_url' => MyCLass::myUrlBuilder('Customer.name')
            ],
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'order' => [
                'Orders.record_num' => 'desc'
            ]
        ])
        ->contain(['Customer'])
        ->toArray();
```

The code will cause an error due to my Url Builder. But I hope you understand what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: What do you mean by "customize" and "manipulating"?

Comment: Basically, the full_url field is not existent, it is just the Customer.name but I need to store the full url of the Customer.name into something like this (https://www.website.com/my-customers-name). But it doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is an [accessor on the entity](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators).